# Classifying data in R based on the text value (R studio)

Tags: r, dataframe, classification

I have a dataframe with companies entries that looks like this:

| Company | Country |
| --- | --- |
| Company 1 | Spain |
| Company 2 | Sweden |
| Company 3 | USA |

I want to add a column based on whether the country is European or not. My final data frame would look like this:

| Company | Country | EU/NONEU |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Company 1 | Spain | EU |
| Company 2 | Sweden | EU |
| Company 3 | USA | NON EU |

thanks a lot!!

Comment: Welcome to SO. You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  may help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `countrycode`-package to identify the continent of a given country and then change the results to `EU` or `NONEU`.

```r
library(countrycode)

df <- read.table(text = "Company    Country
'Company 1'     Spain
'Company 2'     Sweden
'Company 3'     USA", header = TRUE)

df[, 'EU/NONEU'] <- countrycode(sourcevar = df$Country, origin = "country.name", destination = "continent")
df$`EU/NONEU` <- ifelse(df$`EU/NONEU` == "Europe", "EU", "NONEU")
df
#>     Company Country EU/NONEU
#> 1 Company 1   Spain       EU
#> 2 Company 2  Sweden       EU
#> 3 Company 3     USA    NONEU
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

EDIT:
If you have a vector with all countries from the European Union, then it is even easier. You can use `%in%` to check if elements of one vector are in another vector and then use `ifelse()` to assign `EU` and `NONEU`.

```r
eu.countries <- c("Spain", "Sweden")
df$`EU/NONEU` <- ifelse(df$Country %in% eu.countries, "EU", "NONEU")
df
#>     Company Country EU/NONEU
#> 1 Company 1   Spain       EU
#> 2 Company 2  Sweden       EU
#> 3 Company 3     USA    NONEU
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot! The problem with this solution is that this library includes countries such as UK within Europe, and my definition of EU is restricted to the European Union. I was aiming at defining a defining a vector with the EU countries and then using it as a condition for the new column. So if Spain appears as country of the company EU will be directly assigned under the column EU/NONEU.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The problem with this solution is that this library includes countries such as UK within Europe, and my definition of EU is restricted to the European Union. I was aiming at defining a defining a vector with the EU countries and then using it as a condition for the new column. So if Spain appears as country of the company EU will be directly assigned under the column EU/NONEU.

Comment: @CarmenMorenoMartínez if you have a defining vector then it becomes a lot easier, see my edit for a solution.